# Remove simple product from product data woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can we remove simple product and variable product from product data dropdown in woocommerce.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `product_type_selector` filter hook and `unset` to remove `simple` product type. check below code. code will go into the active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'remove_product_types_simple' );
function remove_product_types_simple( $types ){
    unset( $types['simple'] );
    return $types;
}
```